# MySQL returning distinct results for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have tables with listings, categories and one that maps them to each other.  So a listing can then be placed in multiple categories. Something like the following:

```
listings table
    id
    title
    etc

categories table
    id
    category_name
    etc

map table
    listing_id
    category_id
```

When I need to get all of the information for listings within a single category (in this case the category with the id of 18), The following works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`listings`, `map`)
WHERE `map`.`category_id` = 18
AND map.listing_id = listings.id
```

My problem is how can I do a similar type of query, but now I need to find those distinct listings that are within two categories.  For example, what if I need to return only those distinct listings that are in both category_id = 18 AND category_id = 20? Would this require some type of join?

Comment: Do you want to exclude a listing from your result set if it is in more than just the 2 categories you specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to use (another) join. I think the following should do it:

```
SELECT lst.`id`, lst.<column>, ...
FROM `listings` lst, `map` m, `map` m2
WHERE m.`category_id` = 18 AND m2.`category_id` = 20
AND m.`listing_id` = lst.`id`
AND m2.`listing_id` = lst.`id`
```

---

Another version, inspired by Germ's suggestions but this one works (note I replaced `id` with `category_id` for clarity):

```
select l.listing_id
from listings l
join (select m.listing_id, count(*) as cnt from map m where
    m.category_id in (18,20)
    group by m.listing_id) cat_matches
    on cat_matches.listing_id = l.listing_id
where cat_matches.cnt = 2; -- 2 is the number of distinct categories to match
```

Ugly, eh? And the subselect might not be all that efficient... but:

---

```
select l.listing_id
from listings l
join map m on l.listing_id=m.listing_id
where m.category_id in (18,20)
group by l.listing_id
having COUNT(*)=2;
```

You can eliminate that subselect by getting all the rows you need and then filtering them. Note that this solution assumes that the lines in the map table are unique (which should be the case as the PK should be defined on both `listing_id` and `category_id`).

Comment: You'll need to keep joining to the map table each time you need a different category with this method

Comment: Agreed, Germ's solution is probably a better one for this problem.

Comment: The only problem is that Germ's solution (immediately below) doesn't seem to work.  It returns listings if it is in 18 OR 20, but not just those that are in both 18 AND 20 which is what I need to do.

Comment: You're right... I take it back. You need to look at multiple rows in the table to get multiple values. I don't know if there's any way to generalize this for N different category ID's -- aside from dynamically generating SQL queries for different cases.

Comment: I've added a couple more solutions above.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
select * from listings l
join map m on m.listing_id = l.id
join categories c on c.id = m.category_id
where c.id in (18, 20)
```

Comment: @pcampbell: SQL99 JOINs is more accurate

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had some problems getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
select * from listings l, map m, categories c
where l.id = m.listing_id
and m.category_id = c.id
and (c.id = 18 
or c.id = 20)
```

or

```
select * from listings l, map m, categories c
where l.id = m.listing_id
and m.category_id = c.id
and c.id in (18, 20)
```

Comment: That won't even run, you can't have two `WHERE` clauses in a single query.